# Flipping pancakes

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, sorting, stack

In **[pancake sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting)** the only allowed operation is to reverse the elements of some prefix of the sequence. 
Or, think of a stack of pancakes: We insert a spatula somewhere in the stack and flip all the pancakes above the spatula.

For example, the sequence `6 5 4 1 2 3` can be sorted by first flipping the first `6` elements (the whole sequence), yielding the intermediate result `3 2 1 4 5 6`, and then flipping the first `3` elements, arriving at `1 2 3 4 5 6`.

As there is only one operation, the whole sorting process can be described by a sequence of integers, where each integer is the number of elements/pancakes to include pr flip. For the example above, the *sorting sequence* would be `6 3`.

Another example: `4 2 3 1` can be sorted with `4 2 3 2`. Here's the intermediate results:

```
         4 2 3 1
flip 4:  1 3 2 4
flip 2:  3 1 2 4
flip 3:  2 1 3 4
flip 2:  1 2 3 4
```

## The task:

Write a program which takes a list of integers and prints a valid pancake sorting sequence.

The list to sort can either be a space separated list from stdin, or command line arguments. Print the list however it is convenient, as long as it's somewhat readable.

This is codegolf!

#### Edit:

As I said in the comments, **you don't need to optimize the output** (finding the shortest sequence [is NP-hard](http://bit.ly/uvtNe4)). *However*, I just realized that a cheap solution would be to throw out random numbers until you get the desired result (a [new?] type of bogosort). None of the answers so far have done this, so I now declare that **your algorithm should not rely on any (pseudo-)randomness**.

While you're all kicking yourselves, here's a bogopancakesort variant in Ruby 2.0 (60 characters), to rub it in:

```
a=$*.map &:to_i
a=a[0,p(v=rand(a.size)+1)].reverse+a[v..-1]while a!=a.sort
```

Comment: Any valid sequence, or should it be a minimal length one?

Comment: Tiny typo: the second example shows `4 3 2 1` instead of `4 2 3 1`

Comment: (My internet went down as I tried to edit this, so I post it again) @PeterTaylor I was tempted to include some sort of optimization into this, but chose not to. Finding the length of the minimal sequence is [actually NP-hard](http://bit.ly/uvtNe4), while the simplest, straight-forward algorithm can find a solution that at most will be 2n long. I don't really know how I would judge this as a code-challenge/optimal output thing, and I just like plain codegolf more :)

Comment: I wonder if anyone will post their entry from [this challenge](http://codegolf.com/reverse).

Comment: Does the sequence have to be contiguous values? Is 2 7 5 a valid input?

Comment: @hatchet No, it doesn't; 2 7 5 is valid input. There may also be duplicate values, e.g., 2 7 5 5.

Comment: ok, that wasn't obvious from the question. I think some of the answers don't handle those non-contiguous inputs correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### GolfScript, 34 / 21 chars

(Thanks @PeterTaylor for chopping 4 chars off)

```
~].{,,{1$=}$\}2*${.2$?.p)p.@\-+}/,
```

[Online test](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyIyIDEgMSIKfl0ueywsezEkPX0kXH0yKiR7LjIkPy5wKXAuQFwtK30vLA%3D%3D)

A shorter, 21 character version works for lists with unique items only

```
~].${.2$?.p)p.@\-+}/,
```

[Online test](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyI0IDIgMyAxIgp%2BXS4key4yJD8ucClwLkBcLSt9Lyw%3D)

Both versions produce sub-optimal solutions.

---

Explanation for the shorter solution:

```
~]         # read input from stdin
.$         # produce a sorted copy from lowest to highest
{          # iterate over the sorted list
  .2$?     # grab the index of the element
  .p       # print the index
  )p       # increment and print the index
  .@\-+    # move the element to the front
}/
,          # leave the length of the list on the stack
           # this flips the reverse sorted list to become sorted
```

This uses a different algorithm to most of the others posted. Basically it grabs the smallest element of the list, and with two flips moves it to the front, preserving the other elements' order.

To move the nth element to the front:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7   # let's move the 3rd (0-based) element to the front
# flip the first 3 elements
3 2 1 4 5 6 7
# flip the first 3+1 elements
4 1 2 3 5 6 7
```

It repeats this operation for each element in order, and ends up with a reverse sorted list. It then flips the whole list to leave it fully sorted.

---

In fact the algorithm is a variation of a 90-char Python solution (my own, of course):

```
d=map(int,raw_input().split());i=0
while d:n=d.index(max(d));d.pop(n);print n+i,n-~i,;i+=1
```

Comment: I see you haven't come across one of GolfScript's useful quirks: you can use any token as a variable. You're not using `&` anywhere, so you should be able to replace `s` while `&` and remove the whitespace.

Comment: @PeterTaylor huh, I was wondering why you could use `^` as a variable in the fibonacci challenge ;) Thanks for the tip!

Comment: For input `3 2 1` I get `131211` which is not correct.

Comment: @Howard got it to work now

Comment: @Volatility The last change was a bit too much ;-) E.g. lists like `2 1 1` cannot be sorted any more.

Comment: @Howard ahh, dammit. Almost thought I had the lead there! ;)

Answer (score 11):

### Python, <strike>91</strike> 90 chars

```
L=map(int,raw_input().split())
while L:i=L.index(max(L));print-~i,len(L),;L=L[:i:-1]+L[:i]
```

Flip the biggest pancake to the top, then flip the whole stack.  Remove the biggest pancake from the bottom and repeat.

`i` is the index of the biggest pancake.  `L=L[:i:-1]+L[:i]` flips `i+1` pancakes, flips `len(L)` pancakes, then drops the last pancake.

Comment: I thought you were only allowed to make flips. (That is, I didn't think you could drop pancakes from the stack). Did I misunderstand the rules? Hmm. *goes to read wiki page again* Regardless, nice job :) Less than 100 characters is pretty amazing to me!

Comment: @WendiKidd Actually, what he means is that after flipping the biggest one to the bottom, he's just ignoring it and concerning himself with the pancakes on top of it.

Comment: @AJMansfield Ah, I see! Thanks, that makes sense. I can't read the code (I'm too new to Python) so I misunderstood the explanation :)  Thanks!

Comment: Pretty much an evolution of what I wrote before. I didn't think of removing elements because in the beginning I had to check for correctness of the output(i.e. is the list sorted afterwards?). By the way: I believe removing the comma from the `print` wont render the output unreadable(1 byte saved :)

Comment: @WendiKidd actually, on further inspection, it does indeed remove the pancakes; it only needs to figure out what the sequence of flips is, not actually sort the array.

Comment: `print i+1` can be shortened to `print-~i`.

Answer (score 6):

### Ruby 1.9 - <strike>109</strike> <strike>88</strike> 79 characters

Much more compact version based on Keith's great python solution:

```ruby
a=$*.map &:to_i;$*.map{p v=a.index(a.max)+1,a.size;a=a[v..-1].reverse+a[0,v-1]}
```

Original version:

```
a=$*.map &:to_i
a.size.downto(2){|l|[n=a.index(a[0,l].max)+1,l].map{|v|v>1&&n<l&&p(v);a[0,v]=a[0,v].reverse}}
```

If you don't care about spurious operations (reversing stacks of size 1, or reversing the same stack twice in a row) you can make it a bit shorter (96 chars):

```
a=$*.map &:to_i
a.size.downto(2){|l|[a.index(a[0,l].max)+1,l].map{|v|p v;a[0,v]=a[0,v].reverse}}
```

Takes the unsorted list as command-line args.  Example usage:

```
>pc.rb 4 2 3 1
4
2
3
2
```

Answer (score 6):

#### GolfScript, <strike>31</strike> 29 characters

```
~].${1$?).p.2$.,p>-1%\@<+)}%,
```

Another GolfScript solution, can also be tested [online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OyIzIDQgMSAyIgoKfl0uJHsxJD8pLnAuMiQuLHA%2BLTElXEA8Kyl9JSw%3D&run=true).

Previous version:

```
~].$-1%{1$?).2$>-1%@2$<+.,\);}/
```

How does it work: it flips the largest item to the top and then to the last place in the list. Since it is now in the correct position we can remove it from the list.

```
~]         # Convert STDIN (space separated numbers) to array
.$-1%      # Make a sorted copy (largest to smallest)
{          # Iterate over this copy
  1$?)     # Get index of item (i.e. largest item) in the remaining list,
           # due to ) the index starts with one
  .        # copy (i.e. index stays there for output)
  2$>      # take the rest of the list...
  -1%      # ... and reverse it 
  @2$<     # then take the beginning of the list
  +        # and join both. 
           # Note: these operations do both flips together, i.e.
           # flip the largest item to front and then reverse the complete stack
  .,       # Take the length of the list for output
  \);      # Remove last item from list
}/
```

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, <s>103</s> 100 characters

Expects input on the command line.

```
for(@n=sort{$ARGV[$a]<=>$ARGV[$b]}0..$#ARGV;@n;say$i+1,$/,@n+1)
{$i=pop@n;$_=@n-$_-($_<=$i&&$i)for@n}
```

The solutions it prints are decidedly sub-optimal. (I had a program with much nicer output about 24 characters ago....)

The logic is kind of interesting. It starts by cataloguing the index of each item, were it in sorted order. It then iterates through this catalog from right to left. So applying a flip involves adjusting indexes below the cutoff value, instead of actually moving values around. After some finagling I also managed to save a few characters by doing both flips per iteration simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

### Python - 282 characters

```
import sys
s=sys.argv[1]
l=s.split()
p=[]
for c in l:
 p.append(int(c))
m=sys.maxint
n=0
while(n==(len(p)-1)):
 i=x=g=0
 for c in p:
  if c>g and c<m:
   g=c
   x=i
  i+=1
 m=g
 x+=1
 t=p[:x]
 b=p[x:]
 t=t[::-1]
 p=t+b
 a=len(p)-n;
 t=p[:a]
 b=p[a:]
 t=t[::-1]
 p=t+b
 print p
 n+=1
```

My first ever code golf; I'm under no illusions I'll *win*, but I had a lot of fun. Giving everything one-character names sure makes it frightening to read, let me tell you! This is run from the command line, sample implementation below:

```
Python PancakeSort.py "4 2 3 1"
[1, 3, 2, 4]
[2, 1, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

There's nothing particularly special or inventive about the way I've gone about this, but the FAQ suggests posting a non-golfed version for interested readers, so I've done so below:

```
import sys

pancakesStr = sys.argv[1]
pancakesSplit = pancakesStr.split()
pancakesAr = []
for pancake in pancakesSplit:
    pancakesAr.append(int(pancake))

smallestSorted = sys.maxint
numSorts = 0

while(numSorts < (len(pancakesAr) - 1)):
    i = 0
    biggestIndex = 0
    biggest = 0
    for pancake in pancakesAr:
        if ((pancake > biggest) and (pancake < smallestSorted)):
            biggest = pancake
            biggestIndex = i
        i += 1

    smallestSorted = biggest  #you've found the next biggest to sort; save it off.
    biggestIndex += 1   #we want the biggestIndex to be in the top list, so +1.

    top = pancakesAr[:biggestIndex]
    bottom = pancakesAr[biggestIndex:]

    top = top[::-1] #reverse top to move highest unsorted number to first position (flip 1)
    pancakesAr = top + bottom   #reconstruct stack

    alreadySortedIndex = len(pancakesAr) - numSorts;

    top = pancakesAr[:alreadySortedIndex]
    bottom = pancakesAr[alreadySortedIndex:]

    top = top[::-1] #reverse new top to move highest unsorted number to the bottom position on the unsorted list (flip 2)
    pancakesAr = top + bottom   #reconstruct list

    print pancakesAr    #print after each flip

    numSorts += 1

print "Sort completed in " + str(numSorts) + " flips. Final stack: "
print pancakesAr
```

The basic algorithm I used is the one mentioned in the [wiki article linked in the question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting):

> The simplest pancake sorting algorithm requires at most 2n−3 flips. In this algorithm, a variation of selection sort, we bring the largest pancake not yet sorted to the top with one flip, and then take it down to its final position with one more, then repeat this for the remaining pancakes.

Comment: Some tips for golfing: four spaces for indentation is wasteful. Better: use one space; even better: combine tabs and spaces to cut back even more.

Comment: `t=p[:x]` `t=t[::-1]` (16+indentation) can be reduced to `t=p[:x][::-1]` (13), or even `t=p[x-1::-1]` (12). Inline everything you can: `p=p[x-1::-1]+p[x:]`

Comment: Use negative indices to count from the back. `len(a)-n` becomes `-n`; `p=p[-n-1::-1]+p[-n:]`. Further golf by using the right operations: `p=p[~n::-1]+p[-n:]`

Comment: Umm... you are supposed to print the entire flipping sequence, not just the end result.

Comment: What Jan Dvorak said. Welcome to codegolf by the way. You can easily cut the character count to a half by some simple measures; some of them has been mentioned. Also, intermediate variables are no good. [List comprehension](http://bit.ly/VaEG5c) is nice. But if you're using sys.argv you may as well let each number of the input be an argument, then `map(int,sys.argv[1:])` does what your 6 first lines does now. `i=x=g=0` works, but you should cut the amount of variables anyways. I'll give you one thing though: This is the one python entry of which I understand the least :D

Comment: I'm giving you a -1 until the program produces right output, to sort of promote other answers that actually work correctly.

Comment: @daniero Hey, thanks to you and everyone else for the tips! Sorry for misunderstanding the rules, I thought it was just supposed to write the end output. In addition to being new to code golf, I'm pretty new to python; this is my 2nd python program, and I pretty much went along thinking "Okay, now I want to do [x]. Let's google the python syntax for that." ;) But thanks; I'll take a look at all the tips here, and I'll fix the output to match the rules (sorry for misunderstanding!) Also I thought you had to tab-indent in python; good to know a space works!

Comment: @daniero Okay, output fixed to match rules! And I cleared up the whitespace and shaved off 100 characters :D I haven't gone through and added all of the suggestions you guys made because I want to thoroughly understand them before I do (otherwise it feels like cheating!) but I had a lot of fun with this, so thanks for posing the problem! As for your comment about understanding it, I just read the wiki article you linked and followed the logic it gave :) I'm a python newbie so maybe read it as pseudocode instead of python and it will make more sense! ;)

Comment: @WendiKidd Aaaactually that's not quite the desired output either;) See The first example in the question and the part in italics. Or, the output from [http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12029/4372](chron's answer). I guess this is close enough though... Codegolf is a great way to learn the details of a new language by the way!

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2 (254)

Simple BFS-search, some stuff is inlined, probably could be compressed more without changing the search style. Hopefully this shows maybe how to start golfing a bit (too much to be in a simple comment).

Use:

```
python script.py 4 2 3 1
```

(2 spaces = tab)

```
import sys
t=tuple
i=t(map(int,sys.argv[1:]))
g=t(range(1,len(i)+1))
q=[i]
p={}
l={}
while q:
 c=q.pop(0)
 for m in g:
  n=c[:m][::-1]+c[m:]
  if n==g:
   s=[m]
   while c!=i:s+=[l[c]];c=p[c]
   print s[::-1]
   sys.exit()
  elif n not in p:q+=[n];p[n]=c;l[n]=m
```

Comment: You can replace `sys.exit()` with `1/0` (in codegolf you never care for what gets printed in stderr...).

Comment: Sure, I could do `print s[::-1];1/0` to shave a few chars.

Comment: The BFS is very interesting, but running it with `4 2 3 1` gives  `2 3 2 4`, which actually is invalid.

Comment: @daniero How is that output invalid? `4 2 3 1` -> `2 4 3 1` -> `3 4 2 1` -> `4 3 2 1` -> `1 2 3 4`

Comment: @Gareth I have no idea! And I even checked it twice.. Oh well, nevermind then :) Nice solution, miles t.

Answer (score 3):

**Python2: 120**

```
L=map(int,raw_input().split())
u=len(L)
while u:i=L.index(max(L[:u]))+1;L[:i]=L[i-1::-1];L[:u]=L[u-1::-1];print i,u;u-=1
```

It's not efficient: it wont find the best sorting sequence, and the given sequence can even contain no-ops(i.e. flipping only the first element), nevertheless the output is valid.

The output is given in the form:

```
n_1 n_2
n_3 n_4
n_5 n_6
...
```

Which should be read as the sequence of flips: `n_1 n_2 n_3 n_4 n_5 n_6 ...`.
If you want to obtain an output like:

n_1 n_2 n_3 n_4 n_5 n_6 ...

Simply add a comma in the `print` statement.

Comment: `[:i][::-1]` -> `[i-1::-1]`, `[:u][::-1]` -> `[u-1::-1]`, saves 2 chars

Comment: In fact, `L[:i]=L[i-1::-1];L[:u]=[u-1::-1]` saves another 3 chars

Comment: @Volatility Thanks for the tips. Included.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 5.10 (or higher), 66 bytes

Includes `+3` for `-n`
The `use 5.10.0` to bring the language to level perl 5.10 is considered free

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -n
use 5.10.0;
$'>=$&or$.=s/(\S+) \G(\S+)/$2 $1/*say"$. 2 $."while$.++,/\S+ /g
```

Run with the input as one line on STDIN:

```
flop.pl <<< "1 8 3 -5 6"
```

Sorts the list by repeatedly finding any inversion, flipping it to the front then flipping the inversion and flipping everything back to its old position. And that is equivalent to swapping the inversion so I don't need to reverse (which is awkward on strings since it would reverse the digits of the values converting e.g. `12` to `21`)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>72</s> 71 bytes

```hs
h s|(a,x:b)<-span(<maximum s)s=map length[x:a,s]++h(reverse b++a)
h e=e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY4xagMxEEV7neJjUkhILpJ0i/cUKY2LMau1hEdaodGGLXz3jQIG42Zg3n/D/EBy98z7HiAPTW4bruZ0lEJZnxJtMa0JYmRMVMA@31o4bwM5uVgbdPW/vorH1VoyKsCPfheMOH@6L/ft@rwoNfNSIMidP33d6O47EANrMdWe90Uliv/StCiUtf20isPMsciAQyc15oYP9JqvuHpZucV8A0dpb9688MR4/tb9yux/) Finds the maximum, flips it to the back and recursively sorts the remaining list.

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to [BMO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/48198/bmo)*

Answer (score 1):

**C# - 229**

```
using System;using System.Linq;class P{static void Main(string[] a){
var n=a.ToList();Action<int>d=z=>{Console.Write(z+" ");n.Reverse(0,z);};
int c=n.Count;foreach(var s in n.OrderBy(x=>0-int.Parse(x))){
d(n.IndexOf(s)+1);d(c--);}}}
```

readable version

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
class P {
    static void Main(string[] a) {
        var n = a.ToList();
        Action<int> d = z => { Console.Write(z + " "); n.Reverse(0, z); };
        int c = n.Count;
        foreach (var s in n.OrderBy(x => 0 - int.Parse(x))) {
            d(n.IndexOf(s) + 1); d(c--);
        }
    }
}
```