# Can you outgolf Bill Gates?

Tags: code-golf, number, sorting, optimization, stack

> Pancake sorting is the colloquial term for the mathematical problem of
> sorting a disordered stack of pancakes in order of size when a spatula
> can be inserted at any point in the stack and used to flip all
> pancakes above it. A pancake number **P(n)** is the minimum number of
> flips required for **n** pancakes. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting)

In 1979, a young Bill Gates and Christos Papadimitriou, wrote a paper proving an upper bound of **P(n) = (5n+5)/3**. [2](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Echristos/papers/Bounds%20For%20Sorting%20By%20Prefix%20Reversal.pdf)

I think it's safe to assume that Gates (and/or Papadimitriou) wrote a program to perform pancake sorting using the algorithm they developed (possibly  later than 1979). Since Gates was a skilled programmer, they probably tried to golf this code as well as they could, but the size of the source code is not publicly available (AFAIK).

#### Challenge:

Create a function / program that performs pancake sorting, where the maximum number of flips doesn't exceed the bound found by Gates and Papadimitriou.<sup>3</sup> You may choose if you want the list ascending or descending, as long as it's consistent.

You may assume that **n < 50**. You must therefore limit the number of flips to (some randomly selected **n**-values):

```
 n   P(n)
38   65
49   83
50   85
```

The output should be the position of the spatula before each flip. The output may be zero or one-indexed, and you may choose if you count from the top or bottom.

#### Additional rules:

- The runtime must be deterministic
- There is no fixed time limit, but you must be able to provide the output for a list with 50 elements

#### Test lists:

I can't provide the hardest lists (if so, I would write a paper, not a challenge), so I'll provide some random lists of numbers you can test your functions/programs on. I might add others if it turns out these lists where "easy".

```
9, 63, 62, 75, 45, 78, 59, 75, 69, 3, 28, 94, 51, 10, 45, 93, 97, 80, 72, 36, 80, 88, 30, 93, 84, 80, 17, 31, 6, 80, 76, 91, 9, 76, 38, 33, 22, 15, 45, 46, 15, 98, 2, 56, 90, 27, 27, 26, 69, 25
...
74, 89, 57, 52, 70, 96, 16, 5, 77, 84, 54, 13, 90, 64, 31, 80, 3, 25, 13, 19, 13, 34, 1, 79, 35, 43, 4, 19, 82, 29, 48, 95, 97, 28, 45, 62, 64, 82, 70, 34, 38, 15, 51, 83, 21, 66, 4, 42, 74, 84
...
62, 73, 7, 90, 83, 18, 12, 35, 72, 71, 99, 67, 87, 62, 65, 70, 14, 72, 55, 92, 87, 3, 7, 4, 4, 95, 49, 25, 4, 18, 49, 39, 26, 1, 45, 64, 23, 66, 39, 17, 33, 24, 58, 72, 77, 46, 99, 71, 10, 21
```

---

Hopefully, Bill Gates and Papadimitriou will see this challenge, and provide their code, so that we can determine if you did in fact outgolf them.

<sub><sup>3</sup>Better upper bounds have been found, but you do not need to care about those.</sub>

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/12028/31516), but not a duplicate. The answers there wouldn't work here.

Comment: I used BFS in my solution there back then, it should still work here (with slight updating) to find the solution with the minimum number of flips.

Comment: @miles then feel free to post it. I didn't go through all of the answers in detail, but most just used the naive approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Python 2 (PyPy)](http://pypy.org/), <s>238</s> <s>235</s> 222 bytes

```python
a=input();n=len(a);r=range(n);a=zip(a,r);a=map(sorted(a).index,a)+[n]
def s(u,m):
 if m<1:return[0]
 for k in r:
  v=u[k::-1]+u[k+1:]
  if sum(1<abs(v[i]-v[i+1])for i in r)<m:
   p=s(v,m-1)
   if p:return[k]+p
print s(a,5*n/3)
```

*(2 spaces = tab)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5LcsMgEETX1ilmCRFKjP7I1klULEhZTihHmEKSK87lnVZwFgM9Pf1g/H35vLo883d/fzxMb51fF8YPrv8aHTP8EPpg3MfIHD@Y/sd6ZkTY5GQ8m69hGU9IvVp3Gr@F4engdHIazzSzVUy8S8ieaTrKLozLGtyw1wmdr4EuZB2FLtnd@nW4dF0mdQqRyk4nOyDzOjF5NO8zuw1WZzhSqflG2j@SHyfA5HsExJRJjgaY///nolOf@GDdgk2MqF7cW8Efj0EJqgtULqipBJWophVUqdjXuDHOYakSthQk9zGm4KtGUIu@AV7UUbfIFvs4b8voSeQKsM9Ig1uhVVEWG7H9glfkc4myjlphBrvaCJB586w67pZX@hc)

Saved 13 bytes borrowing a method for [ranking a list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/85872/6710).

DFS with a simple heuristic that checks whether a flip separates a pair of "pancakes" that would be adjacent when sorted. Sorts it in ascending order. Output is 0-indexed from the left where 0 flips the first 2 and so on. The number of moves used is `(5/3)*n+1 < 5/3*(n+1)` where `(18/11)*n < (5/3)*n+1 < 5/3*(n+1)` and `(18/11)*n` is a tighter upper bound found in [2009](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397508003575).